# Oracle SQL: How to select the MAX value from a derived column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table (STUFF) with 3 columns (item, old_value, new_value). I would like to retrieve all the items with the highest percentage change in value. The following query produces a "group function is not allowed here" error. How do I go about fixing this?

```
SELECT    item, 
          old_value, 
          new_value, 
          highest_percentage
FROM      (SELECT item, old_value, new_value, 
                  (new_value - old_value) / old_value * 100 AS highest_percentage
          FROM    STUFF)
WHERE     highest_percentage = MAX(highest_percentage);
```

This is the table

```
CREATE TABLE STUFF
( item      VARCHAR2(30) PRIMARY KEY,
  old_value     NUMBER(6, 2),
  new_value     NUMBER(6, 2));

INSERT INTO STUFF VALUES('E1',  0.62,  1.78);
INSERT INTO STUFF VALUES('B1',  0.80,  3.28);
INSERT INTO STUFF VALUES('B2',  2.72,  7.36);
INSERT INTO STUFF VALUES('M4',  2.70,  5.65);
INSERT INTO STUFF VALUES('T6',  5.70,  6.65);
INSERT INTO STUFF VALUES('R3',  4.00, 16.40);
INSERT INTO STUFF VALUES('G10',  8.00, 32.80);
```

Ideally I should have this output.

```
ITEM                OLD_VALUE NEW_VALUE HIGHEST_PERCENTAGE       
------------------- --------- --------- ------------------
B1                  0.80      3.28      310                                    
G10                 8.00      32.80     310                                   
R3                  4.00      16.40     310
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called a Top-N query in Oracle you can do it like:

```
select * from 
    (select * from XXX order by YYY desc) 
  where rownum < N;
```

According to your latest update - a scalar sub-query helps in this case:

```
SELECT * FROM STUFF 
  WHERE (new_value - old_value) / old_value * 100 = 
    (SELECT max((new_value - old_value) / old_value * 100) AS highest_percentage  
        FROM STUFF)
```

To avoid extra sub-querying:

```
SELECT * FROM 
  STUFF,
  (SELECT max((new_value - old_value) / old_value * 100) AS percentage FROM STUFF) highest
WHERE (new_value - old_value) / old_value * 100 = highest.percentage ;
```

However Analytic function seems to be the fastest solution.

Comment: What if you don't know how many rows will have a percentetage equal to the highest percentage ?

Comment: But I don't know the number of items (N) in advance. There could be 1 top item, or 3 like in this case.

Comment: @Anas, group functions are not required since percentage depends on the only row. Otherwise MAX and HAVING should be used.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use a window function that calculates the max percentage while retrieving the data. This is probably faster than the solution with a sub-query as the table only needs to be accessed once:

```
with data as (
  SELECT item, 
         old_value, 
         new_value, 
         (new_value - old_value) / old_value * 100 AS highest_percentage,
         max((new_value - old_value) / old_value * 100) over () as max_pct
  FROM STUFF
)
SELECT item, 
       old_value, 
       new_value, 
       highest_percentage
FROM data   
WHERE highest_percentage = max_pct;
```

Comment: Thanks! This indeed looks more efficient.